# Changing Platform of Existing DLL

Tags: .net, platform, recompile, anycpu

I have a 3rd DLL that is built for "Any CPU".  It needs (for a specific reason) to be rebuilt for x86.  I have no access to the existing source code, but could via Reflector, decompile and recompile it myself.

Is there another way to do this without taking the Reflector path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`corflags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for this. Specifically the `/32BIT+` option. Note the caveats regarding strong named assemblies if applicable.

Comment: Perfect! I'll give that a try.